# Error on inflater.inflate

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-inflate

I have a listview that each item loads a fragment including another fragment inside. The first charge is fine, but when I return to lisview and I reload another fragment (or the same), I get this error on the line:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_text_receiver, container, false);
```

ERROR:

```
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class fragment
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at com.gzanitti.tsar.fragments.ReceiverFragment.onCreateView(ReceiverFragment.java:70)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #43: Duplicate id 0x7f050069, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.gzanitti.tsar.fragments.CommentsFragment
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:296)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
01-11 15:40:59.940: E/AndroidRuntime(14700):    ... 21 more
```

I have no idea what may be happening. The XML file line 34 is where the fragment is declared:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentComments"
        android:name="com.gzanitti.tsar.fragments.CommentsFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtReceiverText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtReceiverText"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtReceiverTitle"/>
```

Maybe some problem with the duplication of ID? Some form of "release"?

EDIT1: fragment_text_receiver.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context=".ReceiverActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtReceiverTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/insertTitle" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtReceiverText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtReceiverTitle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|top"
        android:hint="@string/shareText"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentComments"
        android:name="com.gzanitti.tsar.fragments.CommentsFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtReceiverText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtReceiverText"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtReceiverTitle"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameComments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtShowComments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/showComments"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

EDIT2: receiverFragment.java

```
public class ReceiverFragment extends Fragment {    

public static final int RECEIVER_FRAGMENT = 5;
public static String s3Name;
public static int post_id;
public static String title;
public static String text;
public static int type;
public static File filePath;
protected MediaPlayer mPlayer;
protected View view;
public CommentsFragment fragmentComments;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SesionActivity.actualFragment = RECEIVER_FRAGMENT;
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    title = getArguments().getString("notifTitle");
    text = getArguments().getString("notifText");
    post_id = getArguments().getInt("notifPostID");
    CommentsFragment.post_id = post_id;
    type = getArguments().getInt("notifType");
    s3Name = getArguments().getString("s3Name");

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_text_receiver, container, false);


    EditText txtTextReceiverTitle = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtReceiverTitle);
    txtTextReceiverTitle.setKeyListener(null);
    txtTextReceiverTitle.setText(title);

    EditText txtTextReceiver = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtReceiverText);
    txtTextReceiver.setKeyListener(null);
    txtTextReceiver.setText(text);

    FrameLayout frameComments = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.frameComments);
    frameComments.setOnClickListener(new OnClickReceiverFragmentListener(getActivity(), this));

    FragmentManager fManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentComments = (CommentsFragment) fManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentComments);
    fManager.beginTransaction().hide(fragmentComments).commit();

    return view;
}

@Override 
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.receiver, menu);
} 

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.btnSpread:
            spreadData();
            return true;
        case R.id.btnCancel:
            deleteInSQL();
            backToPendingFragment();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void spreadData() {
    final SesionActivity sActivity = (SesionActivity) getActivity();
    sActivity.pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    sActivity.pDialog.setTitle(getText(R.string.spreading));
    sActivity.pDialog.setMessage(getText(R.string.wait));
    sActivity.pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    sActivity.pDialog.show();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {             
        @Override
        public void run() {         
            TsarServer tServer = new TsarServer(sActivity);
            boolean result = tServer.spread(Integer.toString(ReceiverFragment.post_id), ReceiverFragment.title, ReceiverFragment.text,
                    ReceiverFragment.type, ReceiverFragment.s3Name);
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.obj = result;
            puenteReceiver.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }).start();
}

private Handler puenteReceiver = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {       
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        boolean resPost = (Boolean) msg.obj;    
        ((SesionActivity)getActivity()).pDialog.dismiss();
        if(resPost) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.okPost, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            deleteSource();
            deleteInSQL();
            backToPendingFragment();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.errorPost, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }           
        return true;
    }
});

private void deleteSource() {
    if(ReceiverFragment.filePath != null) {
        File file = new File(ReceiverFragment.filePath.toString());
        file.delete();
    }
}

private void deleteInSQL() {
    PendingSQL sql = new PendingSQL(getActivity(), "dbPending", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = sql.getWritableDatabase();        
    String[] args = new String[]{Integer.toString(ReceiverFragment.post_id)};
    db.delete("pending", "postID=?", args);
}

private void backToPendingFragment() {
    PendingFragment pendingFragment = new PendingFragment();
    FragmentManager fManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    fManager.popBackStack();
    fManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, pendingFragment).commit();
}
```

}

class OnClickReceiverFragmentListener implements OnClickListener{

```
private FragmentActivity mActivity;
private ReceiverFragment mFragment;

public OnClickReceiverFragmentListener(FragmentActivity activity, ReceiverFragment fragment) {
    this.mActivity = activity;
    this.mFragment = fragment;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnPlay:
        ImageButton btnPlay = ((ImageButton) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay));
        if(btnPlay.isEnabled()) {
            mFragment.mPlayer.start();
        }
        break;
    case R.id.btnPause:
        ImageButton btnPause = ((ImageButton) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.btnPause));
        if(btnPause.isEnabled()) {
            mFragment.mPlayer.pause();
        }
        break;
    case R.id.frameComments:
        TextView txtComments = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtShowComments);
        FragmentManager fManager = mFragment.getFragmentManager();
        if(CommentsFragment.isOpen) {
            CommentsFragment.isOpen = false;
            txtComments.setText("Show comments");

            fManager.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom, R.anim.abc_slide_out_bottom)
                .hide(mFragment.fragmentComments)
                .commit();

        } else {
            CommentsFragment.isOpen = true;
            txtComments.setText("Hide comments");   

            fManager.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom, R.anim.abc_slide_out_bottom)
                .show(mFragment.fragmentComments)
                .commit();  
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }       
}

}
```

The first time works fine, but when I come back and try to load another, this error occurs

Comment: post the full xml layout

Comment: check my post the issue should be solved

Comment: You use nested fragment, it has some problems, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608935/best-practice-for-nested-fragments-in-android-4-0-4-1-4-2-without-using-the

Comment: Sorry i thought you had a id duplicated. even in that cast the lint should warn you

Comment: Have you posted `fragment_text_receiver.xml`??. If not post the same

Comment: can you post the fragment code also if you don't mind

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to force the child fragment remove on frament parent detach.

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragmentComments).commit();
}
```