# Show a Fragment in another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I'm trying to show a fragment in another fragment. I'm always doing it like this:

XML:

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

onCreateView of the first fragment:

```
filterFragment = new FilterFragment();

FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, filterFragment);
ft.commit();
```

I'm not using support-fragments. Normally it work's fine, but now I just can see a small bar, which is not "match_parent".
Anyone some ideas?
Thanks for help :)

Comment: I would use `getChildFragmentManager()` for managing nested fragments.

Comment: getChilFragmentManger() requires API level 17 ... my current is 14... i'm looking for a solution without using support-fragment

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608935/best-practice-for-nested-fragments-in-android-4-0-4-1-4-2-without-using-the