# ListFragment onClick DetailFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer with few contents. On click selected navigation content i'm adding ListFragment into activity container. When i clicked on the selected ListFragment position i want to show detail of this selected content. What is the better approach:

1. Replace the MainActivity container(which is ListFragment) by DetailFragment.
2. New DetailActivity which include the DetailFragment.
   Or there is a other approach.

Comment: `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(name)` before commit the fragment transaction

Comment: I don't mean backstack handle. I have a ListFragment, when i clicked on list item i want to replace ListFragment by DetailFragment and i just looking for better approch of this.

Comment: This is the better approach I suggested actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you essentially need to have a `ChildFragment` inside your `ListFragment`

Use `getChildFragmentManager()` inside your ListFragment for your `DetailFragment` transactions. This is the best approach if you need to notify anything to your ListFragment from your DetailFragment in future. 
So your activity will just have the fragment holder for your ListFragment. Your ListFragment will have the fragment holder for your child fragments, in your case, DetailFragment.

Having a separate `DetailActivity` for each list view click is good but not the best approach as you will lose your ListActivity context then.

For reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17132254/1115353

Answer (score 0):

I believe in the most of cases it's better to replace old fragment with a new one when you are switching between drawer menu items. If you go deeper in already existing fragment on MainActivity you should use "add" method with saving fragments in stack.

If you want to change content from Drawer - it's better to replace fragment.
If you want to add new content above existing, like adding details, you should use "add" method

Answer (score 0):

The second approach is the better, where the Gmail app uses that approach.

[image]

[image]